# Keycloak with SPA, How to avoid redirecting

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, single-page-application

My team want to incorporate Keycloak to our spa. But whether it is to verify the login status or refresh the token, redirection to auth server is required, which means a complete reinitialization of SPA.

I want to avoid redirect. But according to [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_modern_browsers), silent SSO check is not supported by modern browsers and will be deprecated in the future. Currently is there any way that I can use Keycloak SSO without redirect?